# Since there is only 1 UI thread - are all event listeners procedural then?

Tags: android, multithreading

Since in Android, every app defaults to 1 single UI thread - does that mean that all event listeners are limited to procedural execution?

(e.g. even if there are 30 buttons on the page) No matter how I click the screen, it is only possible for a single `View.OnClickListener` to activate at a time? Even if I click 2 buttons at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean by "procedural execution"? Do you mean "serial execution"? "it is only possible for a single View.OnClickListener to activate at a time?" -- correct. "Even if I click 2 buttons at the same time?" -- correct. This is why it is very important for listeners to return quickly (sub-millisecond), so we can minimize the impact of the single-threaded UI.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, if you could put what you just said as an answer post, Ill be able to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is only possible for a single View.OnClickListener to activate at a time?

Correct.

> Even if I click 2 buttons at the same time?

Correct. This is why it is very important for listeners to return quickly (sub-millisecond), so we can minimize the impact of the single-threaded UI. Move any work that might be slow — disk I/O, network I/O, long calculations, etc. — to a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and this is very useful when it comes to reasoning about your program.  You never have to worry about things like the order of assignments in methods called in the UI thread, because no other method that runs in the UI thread can run until the current method exits.  For example, if you start an `AsyncTask` in the UI thread, you know that its `onPostExecute` cannot run until the current method returns.  If you use a handler to post something to the main looper, you know that it cannot run concurrently with any component lifecycle method.  Et cetera.